# Laravel GET moved permanently on POST forms 301

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, get

I have this very weird error.

Whenever I attempt to use a form on this particular call, it will automatically do a Moved Permanently 301 call to the exact same page as GET. I'm not sure what is causing this but I'm guessing this is something with how Laravel handles URLs.

For example I have:

```
<?php echo Form::open(array('url' =>  'storage/remove/?page=' . $page)) ?>
```

Where $page is a _GET variable.

When I run this page in FireBug, I see that it always tries to redirect it to a GET page.

My routes:

```
Route::any("storage/{id?}", array("uses" => "StorageController@index", "before" => array("auth", "maintenance_check")));
Route::post("storage/remove", array("uses" => "StorageController@remove", "before" => array("auth", "csrf_check", "maintenance_check")));
```

Can someone let me know what I'm doing wrong for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Perharps the optional `{id}` parameter "catches" the `/remove` segment, therefore the router never triggers `Route::post()`.
Did you try to put `Route::post()` before `Route::any()`?

Answer (score 0):

To to add method `post`:

```
<?php echo Form::open(array('url' =>  'storage/remove/?page=' . $page, 'method' => 'post')) ?>
```